# random rounding

Tags: php, random, rounding

So, i got two numbers, say, A and B.

A is any positive number and B is percentage between 0 and 100.

What i need is percentage B of A, but randomly round up or down, e.g.

```
A = 15, B = 50, result=7(50%) or 8(50%)

A = 10, B = 33, result=3(67%) or 4(33%)
```

My current code is

```
floor($A* ($B + rand(0, 9) ) / 100)
```

But i believe this is not correct and there's better solutions to this.

EDIT:

I've reviewed the answers, and actually tested them([here](http://ideone.com/Voq6le)). The problem with submitted solutions is that they all use rand(0,1) which means that it would always round up or down exacly in 50% of cases. But here's a problem: For example, lets take "A = 10, B = 33" case again. There's basically no difference between if B=31 or B=39. What i wanted it to be is to correspond to percentage(e.g 31 would result 3 in 90% times and 4 in 10% of cases)

From what i can see in answer, it seems that my original solution would work just fine. I should have originally mentioned that it's not just "random rounding" and explain second case a little bit better.

The original idea was that i have an array of, say, 10 items, and i need to get 33% of them. I cant give 3 or 4 of them all the time, because it messes up the whole point of percentage. So i needed it to be at least statistically correct in long run.

But anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: `rand(0,1)?floor($A/100*$B):ceil($A/100*$B)`

Comment: `A = 10, B = 33, result=3(67%) or 4(33%)` - what does this 67% mean?

Comment: oh oh, deleted my answer because sectus is probably onto something. I guess the percentage means a weighted probability for rounding up or down....

Comment: In that case `$B` would be used for both the percentage value of `$A` and as control parameter for the rounding decsion, e.g. down in `$B` % of the dice rolls. Strange.

Comment: Yes, mvw, that's exactly what i wanted.
I liked solution by sectus as the easiest and straightforward solution. I would really like to see this solution to meet needed criteria but i think it would not be that easy anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myround($a, $b) {
    $d = $a * $b / 100.0;
    $f = floor($d);
    if ((rand() / getrandmax()) > ($d - $f)) return $f + 1.0;
    return $f;  
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I went back and read the question very carefully, and this function provides exactly, precisely, in every detail, what the questioner asked for. I see no reason to remove it or to change a single letter of it. I suggest you go re-read the question yourself.

Comment: It does not, actually, correctly answer my question. I edited it with a little more explanation and conclusion. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: You're right, I'd forgotten that PHP only does integers on rand--that's meant to be a random float between 0 and 1. Code fixed.

Comment: You probably meant `(rand() / getrandmax()) < ($d - $f)`. But yeah, this works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than randomly deciding which way to round (which will skew your results randomly, and give you non deterministic functions), why not do what bankers do and "round to even"?

```
echo(round(1.5,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN) . "<br>");
echo(round(-1.5,0,PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN) . "<br>");
```

That way 4.5 rounds to 4 and 3.5 rounds to 4. So 50% of the time your midpoint will round up, and 50% of the time your midpoint will round down, as you desired.

Answer (score 1):

Why not decouple the issues of calculating the percentage and deciding how to round?

```
$X = $A * $B / 100;
$Y = (rand(0,1) > 0) ? floor($X) : ceil($X);
```